# Repeating Functions

Tags: jquery

I am learning J query and building a small project to help to teach myself.

My code seems very long to do what would seem like simple tasks even thou everything works well. I seem to repeating alot of functions like:

```
$("#england").click(function () {

    $('#englandTxt').hide();
    $('#northernIrelandTxt').hide();
    $('#walesTxt').hide();
    $('#scotlandTxt').hide();
    $('#irelandTxt').hide();
    $('#onLoad').hide();
    $("#englandTxt").fadeIn("slow");
     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fy4NP/

how would i tidy this up effectively?

thxs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code would benefit from using classes to identify groups of elements, rather than having to access them all individually. Although there are clever workarounds, I would recommend using classes for targeting similar items in a single operation.

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    $('.txt').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'Txt').fadeIn();
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cTgAy/)

Answer (score 4):

Add a class to them all, such as `country`, so you can change your code to:

```
$("#england").click(function () {
    $('.country:not(#englandTxt)').hide();
    $("#englandTxt").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

`:not()` selector is used so that if england is clicked on twice, it won't `fadeIn` twice.

Comment: You don't necessarily need the `:not(#englandTxt)`, since it is being faded in anyway.

Comment: @Asad Its neater this way. If you clicked on england twice, it would hide it and fade it in again. With my code if you click england when its already open, it wont hide it and display it again.

Answer (score 3):

Use common selectors:

```
//hide all divs
$('div').hide();
```

It would be preferable to give them all a class like `country`, in which case you would use:

```
//hide all divs
$('.country').hide();
```